# when we return from syscall instruction(in x64), is the return stack buffer still valid?

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, cpu, interrupt, cpu-architecture

As we know, when we use "call" instruction, we will create a return address stack buffer in x86&x64 (see http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf p.36) for future prediction of function return address) .

But how about the “syscall” instruction? Will it break the previous return stack buffer when it returns via sysret? Can we view it just like a jmp instruction, only from the perspective of return stack buffer?

### Thank you for your help!

Oh, this is totally not about calling convention but the (branch predict unit) implement of the "syscall" and "sysret" instruction in x64 CPU. The question is not related to the register status before/after the "syscall".

Comment: I would say that it in general should not, but the kernel could call so many functions that the buffer is effectively exhausted when it returns.

Comment: So you agree that syscall is just like a simple jump instruction?

Comment: Nope, it's much more complex. Read the documentation for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on x86-64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64)